# In the definition of a limit for a metric space, what is epsilon?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, definition

A sequence $({\displaystyle x_{n}})$ in a metric space ${\displaystyle M}$ is said to converge to the limit ${\displaystyle x\in M}$ if and only if for every ${\displaystyle \varepsilon >0}$, there exists a natural number N such that ${\displaystyle d(x_{n},x)<\varepsilon }$ for all ${\displaystyle n>N}$.

In this definition, what set does ${\displaystyle \varepsilon}$ belong to - ${\displaystyle M}$  or the real numbers?

Thanks!

Comment: The real numbers.

Comment: $M$ has no order a priori. Moreover a metric is always from $M^2\to \mathbb R^+$. I let you guess where is $\varepsilon $ ;-)

Comment: Remember the elements of a metric space need not to be numbers at all.

Answer (score 1):

A metric space is a set with a topology induced by a distance. Usually, a distance is a function $d:X\times X\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ with certain properties. Here, $d(x_n,x)\in [0,\infty)$ so $\epsilon\in (0,\infty)$. The definition of convergence simply states that no matter how much you choose to be close to $x$ (hence you write for an arbitrary distance $\epsilon >0$) you will find that all elements of the sequence starting from a certain index $N$, are in fact within that arbitrarily (small) distance.